# Cannot unlock BitLocker drive due to "catastrophic media failure or a data structure corruption"

Tags: windows, 64-bit, bitlocker

When trying to unlock my BitLocker drive, I get:

> Unable to complete the requested operation because of either a catastrophic media failure or a data structure corruption on the disk.

This is the screenshot of the error.

How can I recover the data?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Next time please add a readable error message, so others can find it when searching. Thanks.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/bitlocker-unable-to-complete-the-requested/ebe3dbcb-3434-4da9-afb4-7b1ee2d66f10?auth=1

Answer (score 1):

I suspect its due to using a Win 10 computer and the new more secure version of BitLock encryption which is not Win 7 compatible.   Undo BitLock using Win 10 and then try again on Win 7 machine.